# Looping over different column names to condition rows in data table

Tags: r, data.table, rows

The following is an example that has been scaled down.  I am looking for an answer that corrects the following syntax, rather than a "work-around."

```
set.seed(1)
dt = data.table(sum1=rnorm(10,0,1),sum2=rnorm(10,2,1))
catsummax = c(0,3)


df
      sum1       sum2
 1: -0.6264538  3.5117812
 2:  0.1836433  2.3898432
 3: -0.8356286  1.3787594
 4:  1.5952808 -0.2146999
 5:  0.3295078  3.1249309
 6: -0.8204684  1.9550664
 7:  0.4874291  1.9838097
 8:  0.7383247  2.9438362
 9:  0.5757814  2.8212212
10: -0.3053884  2.5939013



for(i in 1:2){
    dt=dt[paste0('sum',i)<=catsummax[i]]
}
```

This drops everything though because data table hates the syntax.

This only keeps rows that, in the first column are <= the first cat sum element, then, only keeps rows that also satisfy the second column's cat max, so it should give out:

```
df
          sum1       sum2
 3: -0.8356286  1.3787594
 6: -0.8204684  1.9550664
10: -0.3053884  2.5939013
```

Comment: `dt=dt[get(paste0('sum',i)) <= catsummax[i]]` ?

Comment: There should be a more elegant way, but this avoids loop: `dt[which(colSums(t(dt) <= catsummax) == length(catsummax))]`

Comment: Chinsoon12, answer for a solution and best with an explanation of get and the syntax how its related to data table

Comment: there should be a better way to do this...so far i can only come up with `dt[apply(sweep(dt, 2, catsummax, function(x, y) x <= y), 1, all)]`. lets wait 24hrs.

Comment: No chinsoon, I asked it the way I did because the data table above is just a selected few columns.  I am looking precisely just to correct the syntax as I said, not find a more efficient workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the object correctly in R for data tables. Data tables are a bit like collections of objects. To call them using a string we use the `get` function. The `get` function basically just grabs the data table entry by object name, using a string. Data tables usually use unquoted strings to do this.

For your exact code, just use

```
for(i in 1:2){
  dt=dt[get(paste0('sum',i))<=catsummax[i],]
}
```

And it will work like a charm.

Comment: FWIW: There might be a performance penalty with this approach for large data.tables and many conditions as the data object is copied for each loop iteration.

Comment: So ideally you want a method to do it simultaneously yeah?

Answer (score 2):

We could use the `Map` to do the  corresponding comparison and `Reduce` it to a single logical `vector` for subsetting the rows

```
dt[, .SD[Reduce(`&`,  Map(`<=`, .SD, catsummax))]]
```

Or

```
dt[dt[, .I[Reduce(`&`,  Map(`<=`, .SD, catsummax))]]]
#         sum1     sum2
#1: -0.8356286 1.378759
#2: -0.8204684 1.955066
#3: -0.3053884 2.593901
```

#### Update

If there are other columns in the dataset, specify the columns of interest in the `.SDcols`

```
dt[, .SD[Reduce(`&`,  Map(`<=`, .SD, catsummax)), .SDcols = sum1:sum2]]
```

Comment: Again the problem is that this assumes the entire data table is the one provided, these are just two columns I want to use for selecting rows of a bigger data table

Comment: @robertevansanders  It was only bcz of your example.  The code remains the same except that you specify `.SDcols`.  It is not a workaround and is a standard data.table syntax

Comment: Imagine instead you had an arbitrary number of columns named sum1...sumJ, you need some way of creating this list of names to call, this is why I wanted it the way I posted

Comment: @robertevansanders  You can use `grep("sum\\d+", names(dt), value = TRUE)` and use that as `.SDcols`

Comment: Why is that preferred, akrun?

Comment: @robertevansanders You meant preferred with respect to `get` ?

Comment: Why is your grep method with SDcols "better" syntax than get?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, got it although I have not quite understand the whole metaprogramming things like call, name, expression, substitute, parse, deparse, eval, quote, enquote

```
i <- paste(paste0("sum", 1:2, " <= ", catsummax), collapse=" & ")
dt[eval(parse(text=i))]
```

Inspiration from:
[R data.table join: SQL "select *" alike syntax in joined tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007282/r-data-table-join-sql-select-alike-syntax-in-joined-tables/37008966#37008966)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, there is also an alternative approach which uses a `non-equi join`:

```
as.data.table(as.list(catsummax))[dt, on = .(V1 >= sum1, V2 >= sum2), nomatch = 0L]
```

> ```
>            V1       V2
> 1: -0.8356286 1.378759
> 2: -0.8204684 1.955066
> 3: -0.3053884 2.593901
> ```

The `on` parameter also can be specified as character vector, i.e.,

```
as.data.table(as.list(catsummax))[dt, on = c("V1>=sum1", "V2>=sum2"), nomatch = 0L]
```

which allows for a more flexible programmatic solution:

If `catsummax` would be specified as `data.table` rather than a vector with the same column names as the ones in `dt` to compare to, e.g.,

```
catsummax_DT <- data.table(sum1 = 0, sum2 = 3)
```

> ```
>    sum1 sum2
> 1:    0    3
> ```

a flexible solution can be created which works on an arbitrary and selectable set of columns:

```
library(magrittr)
cond <- names(catsummax_DT) %>% sprintf("%s>=%s", ., .)
catsummax_DT[dt, on = cond, nomatch = 0L]
```

> ```
>          sum1     sum2
> 1: -0.8356286 1.378759
> 2: -0.8204684 1.955066
> 3: -0.3053884 2.593901
> ```

(`magrittr` is just used for convenience and conciseness)